# How to find duplicates in tuples with Python, using sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, pyqt

I'm new to `Python`, but I'm in love with the language!

I have a huge `sqlite3` database with paths to files in `row 0` and the files `MD5` in `row 3`.

I need to search for duplicate files, based on their `MD5`, and I'd like to organize these duplicates as `dictionaries`, like so:

```
{"b23e5d453643f66b68634d0204884cdf":an array of all paths that have the same MD5, like the one that is the key of this dictionary}
```

I'm using the following code to search the database and make the `tuples`:

```
    db = sqlite3.connect('imges.db')
    with db:
        cur = db.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM IMAGES")
    while True:
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row == None:
            break
        self.duplesOfMD5 = [[row[3]],[row[0]]]
        print self.duplesOfMD5
```

That gives me the following output:

```
[[u'b23e5d453643f66b68634d0204884cdf'], [u'/Volumes/Backup/images_to_test/File_one_copy.png']]
[[u'b23e5d453643f66b68634d0204884cdf'], [u'/Volumes/Backup/images_to_test/File_one.png']]
[[u'f0b4108172c50f243d9e0132df4703a0'], [u'/Volumes/Backup/images_to_test/File_with_no_duplicate.png']]
```

Every possible solution that I've tried where very adequate and the performance was terrible. What's the best pythonic way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
{u'b23e5d453643f66b68634d0204884cdf':
     [u'/Volumes/Backup/images_to_test/File_one_copy.png', u'/Volumes/Backup/images_to_test/File_one.png'],
 u'f0b4108172c50f243d9e0132df4703a0':
     [u'/Volumes/Backup/images_to_test/File_with_no_duplicate.png']
}
```

This is a perfect fit for a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (available since Python 2.5)

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped_by_md5 = defaultdict(list)
db = sqlite3.connect('imges.db')
with db:
    cur = db.cursor()    
    cur.execute("SELECT row1, row3 FROM IMAGES")

    for row1, row3 in cur:
        grouped_by_md5[row3].append(row1)
```

Comment: Yes, you got it right and your solution seems to be very good, but I'm getting an error message. Please see my comments under alecxe response to me.

Comment: you just need to change to for row1, row3 in cur:, as suggested by alecxe.

Comment: @Winston yeah, it makes more sense like this

Answer (score 2):

You can put `cur` in a loop, retrieve only columns you are actually using and use tuple unpacking in the loop like this:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('imges.db')
with db:
    cur = db.cursor()    
    cur.execute("SELECT row1, row3 FROM IMAGES")

    for row1, row3 in cur:
        print [[row3],[row1]]
```

Also, why don't use `DISTINCT`?

```
cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT row1, row3 FROM IMAGES")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got this error message: for row1, row3 in cur.fetchone(): ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @Winston are you sure that you are selecting only 2 fields?

Comment: In the place of row1 I'm putting URL, and int the place of row3 i'm putting MD5, which are the names of my rows.

Comment: @Winston please see updated answer, try to iterate over cursor: `for row1, row3 in cur`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine by MD5, you will want to first have the list sorted by MD5. This is best left to sqlite in your case, so you should add to your query an order by (see e.g., https://mariadb.com/kb/en/order-by-clause/). After that you should loop through all the rows and do something along the following lines:

```
if currentMD5 != previousMD5:
  dictionary[currentMD5] = [currentFilePath]
else:
  dictionary[currentMD5].append(currentFilePath]
currentMD5 = previousMD5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm analyzing the best way to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. I changed the link to something more prudent.